# react native navigation 5 log out from the bottom tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

in version 4
navigation.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      key: null,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Login'})],
    }),
  );

version 5

I can't use StackActions.reset and NavigationActions
What should i do ?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Can you provide some code and examples of what exactly you want to achieve? Like the current navigation structure and what you want it to become.

Answer (score 0):

NativgtionActions has been removed in V5 and CommonActions has been introduced ...
So here is possible approach try that

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Profile',
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      },
    ],
  })
);
```

make sure you replace reset block with your Login route
 A detailed reference is here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html